# How to call the browsers or drivers from properties file in webdriver?

Tags: webdriver

Could anyone help me on the above query.

property file contains as browser=Mozilla

How we call this in webdriver.

because i need to change only the browser value in property file like firefox, chrome or IE , so that i don't want to change in webdriver code, so please help me with the code.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1 :** Create file and put values like below in it and place it in some package.

e.g config.properties

```
firstname=harry
lastname=mohan
```

**Step 2 :** Use `System.getProperty("user.dir")` to get the relative path of workspace . This way you can make config.properties as machine independent

**Step 3 :** Use below code . It has all detail about further steps

```
package test;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;
public class propfilelearning {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

  //Create Object of Properties Class

  Properties prop = new Properties();

  //Use System.getProperty to get the relative path of file in Workspace. Now file path is machine independent.
  String path = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\src\\test\\config.properties";
  System.out.println("Actual Location of File -> " + path);


  //Create FileInputStream object of Config/data file
  FileInputStream fs= new FileInputStream(path);

  // Pass fs object to load method of Properties object

  prop.load(fs);

  // Use getProperty method of Properties object to get the values.

  System.out.println(prop.getProperty("firstname"));
  System.out.println(prop.getProperty("lastname"));

 }
}
```

Comment: I would like to know about how the browsers like firefox, chrome, IE can be called from properties file